# JQuery mobile iFrame inside popup content doesn't reload or close properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, iframe, popup

I am using JQuery Mobile to load some content from a different page into an iframe in a popup and displaying that iframe content within that popup on my initial page.

My popup link is as follows:

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop" data-position-to="window">
```

My popup is defined as follows:

```
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic" data-overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    </div>
```

As you can see it has a close button.

I open my popup when a list item in a listview is tapped as follows:

```
    $('#myList').delegate('li', 'tap', function () {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $("#popupBasic #memberFrame").remove();
    $("#popupBasic").append( '<iframe src="/myPage?id=' + index + '" height="400px;" width="100%;" id="memberFrame"></iframe>' );
    });
```

As you can see this loads the page with a specific id based on the index, the popup opens and this content gets loaded in the iframe within the popup.

On my iframe content there is a button and a count, when the button is pressed the page refreshes and the count should be increased. This is done by the server. However while I can see the count is getting increased and the page looks it gets refreshed it appears the content within the iframe is getting cached or something as when the page refreshes the old count is there.

Two things to add to this:

1: If I then manually refresh the iFrame by right clicking on it and selecting the refresh frame option it works OK

2:The popup has a close button on it and when I click this the first time it doesn't close the popup, instead it looks like it refreshes the iframe content and this time the count is correct. Then pressing the close a second time actually closes the popup

The experience in #2 I find very odd and I was wondering if anyone could help point out why this might be occurring?

Comment: you need to refresh/reload/re-append `iframe` into popup div. for #2 is popup's direct parent _page div_ or a different div?

Comment: So I need to look into how I can re-append the iframe into the popup in my initial page after the button has been clicked on the iframe content and it has been reloaded? For #2 the content is in a different html page but it is a JQuery mobile page also with a page div

Comment: #2 Make sure that direct parent of _popup_ div is _page_ div. e.g. `<div data-role=page> <div data-role=popup> </div> </div>`. To re-append `iframe`, simply `var iframe = $("#popupID iframe"); $("#popupID iframe").replaceWith(iframe);`. **Edit:** http://stackoverflow.com/a/20317380/1771795

Comment: Great, I'll try that, is there a way for me to detect when the content on the iframe has reloaded? The iframe content is in a different page so I can't reference it in the page where the pop up is.

Comment: Also I tried wrapping the popup with <div data-role="page"> but now my popup doesn't open

Comment: you shouldn't wrap it, just place it as a child of page div. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17388111/1771795

Comment: Ah OK I get you now, after doing that the behaviour is the same though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55915/discussion-between-donal-rafferty-and-omar).